# explanation of the following syntax : 'ATYPE

Tags: haskell

I've seen this syntax `ReadResult 'RegularStream StreamSlice`, could you explain what does the `'` mean before a data type ?

Comment: Is this the same thing as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44865000/1364007)?

Comment: @WaiHaLee Yes, it's the same mechanism. To the OP: if you feel that the linked question does not answer fully, we can reopen the question.