# Filter a list by returning only one kind of data constructor instead of the type of the type constructor

Tags: haskell

So let's say I have the following data type :

```
data CommandRequest  = CreateWorkspace {commandId :: UUID , workspaceId ::UUID }
                 | IntroduceIdea {commandId :: UUID , workspaceId ::UUID , ideaContent :: String} deriving (Show,Eq)
```

with the `{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds   #-}`

I want to implement the following function (in pseudocode) :

```
filter :: [CommandRequest] -> [CreateWorkspace] (promoting the data constructor to a type level)
```

can you help me with the implementation of that function ?... Thank you !

Comment: please go over the syntactic issue (I added the mention pseudocode to be clearer), I want to promote a data constructor...

Comment: Even if you somehow managed to lift `UUID` to the type level, you have a problem: `[] :: * -> *`, but `CreateWorkspace :: UUID -> UUID -> CommandRequest`, a kind that is clearly distinct from `*`. So `[CreateWorkspace]` is not well-kinded. Can you say what you would want the type `[CreateWorkspace]` to mean (since on its own it does not have a meaning)? Are you sure you don't just want `myFilter :: [CommandRequest] -> [(UUID, UUID)]`?

Comment: (In particular, I suspect you are thinking, "The type of `CreateWorkspace` data values is the `CreateWorkspace` type!". But this is not at all true. Indeed, there are no terms whose type has `CreateWorkspace` as its outermost constructor.)

Comment: please have a look here : https://gitlab.com/YoEight/eventstore-hs/blob/dev/1.0/Database/EventStore.hs at readStreamEventsCommon function, you'll see that they are returning IO (Async (ReadResult 'RegularStream StreamSlice))  with data StreamType = All | RegularStream deriving (Eq, Ord). and if you look there (https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism-and-promotion.html) they are saying : "With -XDataKinds, GHC automatically promotes every suitable datatype to be a kind, and its (value) constructors to be type constructors"

Comment: I'm a fan of dependent types and my impression was that with that I could define by example a List of one value constructor like ['True] or ['Nothing], but maybe I'm dreaming...

Comment: Meanwhile, if *you* look at the source of `ReadResult s a`, you'll see that it doesn't store a value of type `s` (and can't, because `s` has the wrong kind). A `ReadResult 'RegularStream StreamSlice` doesn't have a value constructed by the data constructor `RegularStream` in it. So I think `ReadResult` doesn't do what you think it does -- and it motivates my question, "what do you think/want this to do?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a Haskell type like:

```
data Foo = Bar Int | Baz String
```

there is no direct way of writing down a new type that represents the subset of values of type `Foo` that are constructed with `Bar`, **even** using the `DataKinds` extension.

In particular, when you turn on `DataKinds`, the `Bar` type that you get is *not* the type of the values `Bar 1` and `Bar 2`.  In fact, the new lifted `Bar` type doesn't really have anything to do with the values `Bar 1` and `Bar 2`, except for the fact that they share the name `Bar`.  It's not that different than explicitly defining:

```
data True = TrueThing
```

This new type `True` has nothing to do with the value `True` of type `Bool`, except they happen to have the same name.

Presuming that what you are *trying* to do is find a type-safe way of representing the result of filtering `CommandRequest` for just those values that were constructed with the `CreateWorkspace` constructor so that you can't "accidentally" let an `IntroduceIdea` sneak in to your list, you'll have to take another approach.  There are several possibilities.

The most straightforward way, which doesn't require any special type-level programming at all, is to represent `CreateWorkspace` and `IntroduceIdea` as separate types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
data CreateWorkspace = CreateWorkspace
  { commandId :: UUID
  , workspaceId ::UUID
  } deriving (Show)
data IntroduceIdea = IntroduceIdea
  { commandId :: UUID
  , workspaceId ::UUID
  , ideaContent :: String
  } deriving (Show)
```

and then create a new algebraic sum type to represent the disjoint union of those separate types:

```
data CommandRequest
  = CreateWorkspace' CreateWorkspace
  | IntroduceIdea' IntroduceIdea
  deriving (Show)
```

Note we've used the ticks to differentiate these constructors from those used in the underlying component types.  A simple variant of this would be to move common fields (like `commandId`, and perhaps `workSpaceId`) into the `CommandRequest` type.  This might or might not make sense, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Anyway, this adds a little syntactic fluff, but it's straightforward to define:

```
filterCreateWorkspace :: [CommandRequest] -> [CreateWorkspace]
filterCreateWorkspace crs = [ cw | CreateWorkspace' cw <- crs ]
```

and with some additional "constructors":

```
createWorkspace :: UUID -> UUID -> CommandRequest
createWorkspace u1 u2 = CreateWorkspace' (CreateWorkspace u1 u2)

introduceIdea :: UUID -> UUID -> String -> CommandRequest
introduceIdea u1 u2 s = IntroduceIdea' (IntroduceIdea u1 u2 s)
```

it's not too hard to create and filter `[CommandRequest]` lists:

```
type UUID = Int
testdata1 :: [CommandRequest]
testdata1
  = [ createWorkspace 1 2
    , createWorkspace 3 4
    , introduceIdea 5 6 "seven"
    ]

test1 = filterCreateWorkspace testdata1
```

giving:

```
> test1
[CreateWorkspace {commandId = 1, workspaceId = 2}
,CreateWorkspace {commandId = 3, workspaceId = 4}]
```

This is almost certainly the correct approach for doing what you want to do.  I mean, this is exactly what algebraic data types are **for**.  This is what a Haskell program is **supposed** to look like.

"But no," I hear you say!  "I want to spend endless hours fighting confusing type errors!  I want to crawl down the dependent type rabbit hole.  You know, for 'reasons'."  Should I stand in your way?  Can one man stand against the ocean?

If you really want to do this at the type level, you *still* want to define separate types for your two constructors:

```
data CreateWorkspace = CreateWorkspace
  { commandId :: UUID
  , workspaceId ::UUID
  } deriving (Show)
data IntroduceIdea = IntroduceIdea
  { commandId :: UUID
  , workspaceId ::UUID
  , ideaContent :: String
  } deriving (Show)
```

As before, this makes it easy to represent a list of type `[CreateWorkspace]`.  Now, the key to working at the type level will be finding a way to make it as difficult as possible to represent a list of type  `[CommandRequest]`.  A standard method would be to introduce a `CommandRequest` type class with instances for our two types, together with an existential type to represent an arbitrary type belonging to that class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

type UUID = Int   -- for the sake of examples

data CreateWorkspace = CreateWorkspace
  { commandId :: UUID
  , workspaceId ::UUID
  } deriving (Show)
data IntroduceIdea = IntroduceIdea
  { commandId :: UUID
  , workspaceId ::UUID
  , ideaContent :: String
  } deriving (Show)

class CommandRequest a where
    maybeCreateWorkspace :: a -> Maybe CreateWorkspace
instance CommandRequest CreateWorkspace where
    maybeCreateWorkspace c = Just c
instance CommandRequest IntroduceIdea where
    maybeCreateWorkspace _ = Nothing

data SomeCommandRequest = forall t . CommandRequest t => SomeCommandRequest t
```

Now we can define:

```
import Data.Maybe

filterCreateWorkspace :: [SomeCommandRequest] -> [CreateWorkspace]
filterCreateWorkspace = catMaybes . map getCW
  where getCW (SomeCommandRequest cr) = maybeCreateWorkspace cr
```

which works fine, though the syntax is still a bit cumbersome:

```
testdata2 :: [SomeCommandRequest]
testdata2 = [ SomeCommandRequest (CreateWorkspace 1 2)
           , SomeCommandRequest (CreateWorkspace 3 4)
           , SomeCommandRequest (IntroduceIdea 5 6 "seven")
           ]
test2 = print $ filterCreateWorkspace testdata2
```

The test gives:

```
> test2
[CreateWorkspace {commandId = 1, workspaceId = 2}
,CreateWorkspace {commandId = 3, workspaceId = 4}]
```

The awkward thing about this solution is that we need a type class method for identifying the `CreateWorkspace` type.  If we wanted to construct lists of each possible constructor, we'd need to add a new type class method for every single one, and we need to give a definition for the method for every instance (though we can get away with a default definition that returns `Nothing` for all but one instance, I guess).  Anyway, that's nuts!

The mistake we made was making it *difficult* to represent a list of type `[CreateWorkspace]` instead of **absurdly difficult**.  To make it absurdly difficult, we'll still want to represent our two constructors as separate types, but we'll make them instances of a data family keyed by constructor names lifted to the type level by the `DataKinds` extension.  *Now* this is starting to look like a Haskell program!

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data CommandRequestC = CreateWorkspace | IntroduceIdea
data family CommandRequest (c :: CommandRequestC)

type UUID = Int   -- for the sake of examples
data instance CommandRequest CreateWorkspace
  = CreateWorkspaceCR
  { commandId :: UUID
  , workspaceId ::UUID
  } deriving (Show)
data instance CommandRequest IntroduceIdea
  = IntroduceIdeaCR
  { commandId :: UUID
  , workspaceId ::UUID
  , ideaContent :: String
  } deriving (Show)
```

What's going on here?  Well, we introduced a new type `CommandRequestC` (the trailing `C` stands for "constructor") with two constructors `CreateWorkspace` and `IntroduceIdea`.  The only purpose of these constructors was to lift them to the type level using `DataKinds` in order to use them as type-level tags for the `CommandRequest` data family.  This is a very common way of using `DataKinds`, maybe the *most* common.  In fact, the example you gave of the type `ReadResult 'RegularStream StreamSlice` was **exactly** this kind of usage.  The type:

```
data StreamType = All | RegularStream
```

carries no useful data.  The whole point of its existence is to lift the constructors `All` and `RegularStream` to type-level tags, so that `ReadResult 'All StreamSlice` and `ReadResult 'RegularStream StreamSlice` can be used to name two different related types, just like `CommandRequest 'CreateWorkspace` and `CommandRequest 'IntroduceIdea` name two different related types.

At this point, we have two separate types for our two constructors that happen to be related via a tagged data family, rather than via a type class.

```
testdata3 :: [CommandRequest 'CreateWorkspace]
testdata3 = [CreateWorkspaceCR 1 2, CreateWorkspaceCR 3 4]

testdata4 :: [CommandRequest 'IntroduceIdea]
testdata4 = [IntroduceIdeaCR 5 6 "seven"]
```

Note that even though we can write the type `[CommandRequest c]`, leaving the constructor tag as an unspecified type variable `c`, we still can't write a list that mixes these constructors:

```
testdata5bad :: [CommandRequest c]
testdata5bad = [CreateWorkspaceCR 1 2, CreateWorkspaceCR 3 4, 
            IntroduceIdeaCR 5 6 "seven"]  -- **ERROR**
```

We still need our existential type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data SomeCommandRequest = forall c . SomeCommandRequest (CommandRequest c)
```

and the extra existential syntax:

```
testdata6 :: [SomeCommandRequest]
testdata6 = [ SomeCommandRequest (CreateWorkspaceCR 1 2)
            , SomeCommandRequest (CreateWorkspaceCR 3 4)
            , SomeCommandRequest (IntroduceIdeaCR 5 6 "seven")]
```

Worse yet, if we try to write a filter function, it's not clear how to implement it.  One reasonable first attempt is:

```
filterCreateWorkspace :: [SomeCommandRequest] -> [CommandRequest 'CreateWorkspace]
filterCreateWorkspace (SomeCommandRequest cr : rest)
   = case cr of cw@(CreateWorkspaceCR _ _) -> cw : filterCreateWorkspace rest
                _ -> filterCreateWorkspace rest
```

but this fails with an error about failing to match to the `CreateWorkspace` tag.

The problem is that data families aren't powerful enough to allow you to infer which member of a family you actually have (i.e., whether `cr` is a `CreateWorkspaceCR` or `IntroduceIdeaCR`).  At this point, we could go back to working with a type class or maybe introduce proxies or singletons to maintain a value-level representation of the constructors in the existential type, but there's a more straightforward solution.

GADTs *are* powerful enough to infer the type of `cr`, and we can rewrite our data family as a GADT.  Not only is the syntax simpler:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

data CommandRequestC = CreateWorkspace | IntroduceIdea

type UUID = Int
data CommandRequest c where
  CreateWorkspaceCR :: UUID -> UUID -> CommandRequest 'CreateWorkspace
  IntroduceIdeaCR :: UUID -> UUID -> String -> CommandRequest 'IntroduceIdea
deriving instance Show (CommandRequest c)

data SomeCommandRequest = forall c . SomeCommandRequest (CommandRequest c)
```

but we can implement our filtering function without fuss:

```
filterCreateWorkspace :: [SomeCommandRequest] -> [CommandRequest 'CreateWorkspace]
filterCreateWorkspace crs
  = [ cw | SomeCommandRequest cw@(CreateWorkspaceCR _ _) <- crs ]
```

define some helpful "constructors":

```
createWorkspace :: UUID -> UUID -> SomeCommandRequest
createWorkspace u1 u2 = SomeCommandRequest (CreateWorkspaceCR u1 u2)

introduceIdea :: UUID -> UUID -> String -> SomeCommandRequest
introduceIdea u1 u2 s = SomeCommandRequest (IntroduceIdeaCR u1 u2 s)
```

and test it:

```
testdata7 :: [SomeCommandRequest]
testdata7 = [ createWorkspace 1 2
            , createWorkspace 3 4
            , introduceIdea 5 6 "seven"]
test7 = filterCreateWorkspace testdata7
```

like so:

```
> test4
[CreateWorkspaceCR 1 2,CreateWorkspaceCR 3 4]
>
```

Does any of this look familiar?  It should, because it's @chi's solution.  And it's the only type-level solution that really makes sense, giving what you're trying to do.

Now, with a couple of type aliases and some clever renaming, you can *technically* get the type signature you want, like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

data CommandRequestC = CreateWorkspaceC | IntroduceIdeaC
type CreateWorkspace = ACommandRequest 'CreateWorkspaceC
type IntroduceIdea = ACommandRequest 'IntroduceIdeaC

type UUID = Int
data ACommandRequest c where
  CreateWorkspaceCR :: UUID -> UUID -> CreateWorkspace
  IntroduceIdeaCR :: UUID -> UUID -> String -> IntroduceIdea
deriving instance Show (ACommandRequest c)

data CommandRequest = forall c . CommandRequest (ACommandRequest c)

filterCreateWorkspace :: [CommandRequest] -> [CreateWorkspace]
filterCreateWorkspace crs
  = [ cw | CommandRequest cw@(CreateWorkspaceCR _ _) <- crs ]

createWorkspace :: UUID -> UUID -> CommandRequest
createWorkspace u1 u2 = CommandRequest (CreateWorkspaceCR u1 u2)

introduceIdea :: UUID -> UUID -> String -> CommandRequest
introduceIdea u1 u2 s = CommandRequest (IntroduceIdeaCR u1 u2 s)

testdata8 :: [CommandRequest]
testdata8 = [ createWorkspace 1 2
            , createWorkspace 3 4
            , introduceIdea 5 6 "seven"]

test8 = filterCreateWorkspace testdata8
```

but this is just a trick, so I wouldn't take it too seriously.

And, if all this seems like a lot of work and leaves you feeling dissatisfied with the resulting solution, then welcome to the world of type-level programming!  (Actually, it *is* all kind of fun, but try not to expect too much.)

Comment: Thanks for having spent the time to explain ;-) It was really helpful !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to filter only those values obtained through a specific constructor. Note that the type of the list does not change.

```
filter :: [CommandRequest] -> [CommandRequest]
filter xs = [ x | x@(CreateWorkspace{}) <- xs ]
```

---

If you want a more precise type, you need more complex type-level machinery, like GADTs.

Here's an untested approach. You'll need a few extensions to be turned on.

```
data CR = CW | II  -- to be promoted to "kinds"

-- A more precise, indexed type
data CommandRequestP (k :: CR) where
   CreateWorkspace :: {commandId :: UUID, workspaceId ::UUID }
      -> CommandRequestP 'CW
   IntroduceIdea :: {commandId :: UUID, workspaceId ::UUID, ideaContent :: String}
      -> CommandRequestP 'II

-- Existential wrapper, so that we can build lists
data CommandRequest where
    C :: CommandRequestP k -> CommandRequest

filter :: [CommandRequest] -> [CommandRequestP 'CW]
filter xs = [ x | C (x@(CreateWorkspace{})) <- xs ]
```

Comment: I would like the function to be typed '[CreateWorkspace] not [CommandRequest]

Comment: @NicolasHenin That's impossible, since that is not a type. Value constructors are not types, `[CreateWorkspace]` is not a type, and `'[CreateWorkspace]` is not a type either. Perhaps you need a GADT, singletons, and some more complex type-level machinery, but I'm unsure about what you really want/need.

Comment: I want to filter and better type my result (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865000/what-does-an-apostrophe-in-front-of-a-list-something-mean-in-haskell) I was thinking it's possible by using DataKinds extension. you wrote "This is DataKinds in action, which:

lifts values at the type level, and
lifts types to the kind level
" Sorry there is something I don't understand then...

Comment: if you look at the lib https://gitlab.com/YoEight/eventstore-hs/blob/dev/1.0/Database/EventStore.hs at readStreamEventsCommon function, you'll see that they are returning IO (Async (ReadResult 'RegularStream StreamSlice)) which is the kind of stuff I would like to do

Comment: with data StreamType = All | RegularStream deriving (Eq, Ord)